# Read Access Violation in (Vector ? ) destructor

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I am writing a class that has member functions that take a few input files and generate a stream of requests that are stored in a class member.

However once the test ends I get a read access violation when the default destructor executes. I can't figure out the reason for this.

Here is the .hpp file that describes the class, Can someone point out any flaws in the basics here ?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include <memory>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <map>
#include "SimDataTypes.h"

using namespace std; 

#define dataSize 64 
#define SEARCH_RANGE 40 
#define DEBUG_STREAM 1 
#define BLOCKSIZE 256 //256 Byte alignment 



class CacheReqStream
{
    struct CacheReq
    {
        CC_UINT8 data[256]; //at most 256 bytes  
        vector<CC_UINT32> size;
        vector<CC_UINT64> addr;
        vector<CC_UINT64> timeStamp;
        CC_UINT64 baseAddr;
        string surf;
        string tile;
        access_type access;
        vector< string > client; 
        CC_UINT32 dataMask; //Which addr to write the 32 bytes to. (Alahiry Revise description)
        CC_UINT32 addrMask; //Which 64 Byte chunk of the 256 Byte aligned Addr ( 4 bit mask that says which addresses are valid)
    };

struct AddrList
{
    vector<string> data; 
    vector<CC_UINT64> addr; 
    vector<CC_UINT64> timeStamp; 
    vector<access_type> access;
    vector<CC_UINT32> size ;
    vector<CC_UINT64> Index; //Index in the file for that addr.
    vector<string> surf; 
    vector<string> tile; 
    vector<string> client; 
    bool initialized; 
    bool anyWrites; 
};

map<CC_UINT64, AddrList> AddrMap; //store base address and list of all accesses in that range
vector< shared_ptr<CacheReq> > reqStream; //store processed addresses 


//Check if the address for that timeStamp and Client is already processed for the same access type.
bool isProcessed(CC_UINT64 address, string Client , access_type access, CC_UINT64 timeStamp);

//void CheckNeighbors(CC_UINT64 addrIn[], vector< shared_ptr<CC_UINT8> > dataIn, access_type accessIn[], int start, access_type type, CC_UINT64 startAddr, CacheReq* req); 
void CheckNeighbors(string dataIn, int start, access_type type, CC_UINT64 startAddr, shared_ptr<CacheReq> req);

//void findAndStore(CC_UINT64 addrIn[], vector< shared_ptr<CC_UINT8> > dataIn, access_type accessIn[], int start, access_type type);
void findAndStore(string dataIn, int start, CC_UINT64 addr, access_type type,string surf, string tile, string client, CC_UINT64 time);

//total data requested must equal the total data in the created stream  
void verifyStream(void);

//Create an access from the addresses stored in the AddrMap at this point in time. 
void createReadAccess(string dataIn, int start, CC_UINT64 addr, string surf, string tile, string client, CC_UINT64 time);

//Create an access from the addresses stored in the AddrMap at this point in time. 
void createWriteAccess(string dataIn, int start, CC_UINT64 addr, string surf, string tile, string client, CC_UINT64 time);

//Get the index to store the addr based on the bottom two bits( 0x00 = index 0 ; 0x40  == index 1  0x80 == index 2 0xC0 == index 3)
//This assumes 64 byte stream with 256 byte access stream
CC_UINT32 getAddrIndex(CC_UINT64 addr);

//Get the index to the 32 byte chunk in the data segment 
CC_UINT32 getDataSegIndex(CC_UINT64 addr);

//Get Index of access currently requested
CC_UINT32 getAccessIndex(CC_UINT64 addr, CC_UINT64 time, string client);
//Align addresses to the cache block size 
CC_UINT64 alignDown(CC_UINT64 address);

tiling_formats convertTile(string tile);
surface_formats convertFormat(string format); 

//CC_UINT64 partialMasks; 


public:

    CC_UINT64 getAddr(int index);
    CC_UINT32 getSize(int index);
    tiling_formats getTiling(int index);
    surface_formats getSurfFormat(int index);
    access_type getAccess(int index);

//Create a stream of accesses clubbed together.
void ProcessData(void);
//accumulate data structure per aligned addr. 
void accumulateAddr(void);
};
```

The issue occurs while the destructor is clearing the 'reqStream' vector. 
Here is the call stack from visual studio.

[image]

I am wondering if I need to describe a destructor here or should the default handle the vector and map members correctly ?

Comment: Yup sorry about that, bad choice of words. I am not deleting reqStream. The default destructor is trying to clear the shared_ptrs I think ?  The read access violation occurs in the default destructor.

Comment: have you tried comming up with a [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: Not yet. Will try creating one later this evening. I was wondering if the issue was obvious due to lack of specific constructor/destructor described in the class.

Comment: I would start with investigating whether there's any out-of-bounds shenanigans going on with `CacheReq::data`.

Comment: There is only one member function that modifies CacheReq::data and it can't go out of bounds from what I can tell. However CacheReq::data is uninitialized and the function only writes parts of the data[256] based on certain conditions.  I am rerunning with `data[256]={} ; ` to make sure it is zero initialized.

Comment: Thanks molbdnilo, It was actually an out-of-bounds write that was causing this issue. Can you provide your comment as an answer so I can accept it ?

Comment: @akslah Sorry to unearth your question 4 years afterwards, but can you provide more information on how an OOB write caused the vector destructor to improperly destroy shared_ptrs? That is, if you can remember. I am currently facing the exact same issue and don't really know what to look for or whereabouts to look for it.

Answer (score 1):

There's good reference here: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/memory/shared_ptr/
You'll have to include a destructor in CacheRegStream which releases ownership of the vector of shared pointers, rather than attempting to delete the vector. (The default destructor is trying to destroy shared pointer which is still owned by other objects, essentially trying to delete their members, which is out of bounds.)

A special case for the destructor to handle is the last owning object is responsible for destroying the shared pointer vector when it is destroyed. Normally shared pointers would handle this by default, but since it is a vector, the vector destructor is being called as well (which also destroys all vector elements), but doesn't have the permission to destroy what is co-owned by other objects.

Comment: Thanks, while this was not the root cause, It was a potential bug in my code that I fixed.